# Is there a way to feed extra data to the loss function while training the neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function

So my dataset have 3 parts: inputs (X), outputs (Y), and a part provides extra information (Z)

What I want to do is to somehow put Z in the loss function so it can be calculated with Y. Is there a way to do that? It seems the size of Z will not match the batch size I defined. Should I just put all data in a single batch?

I try to put Z as output too and only use Y part in the loss function as the output. It returns the error No gradients provided for any variable: (['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0', 'dense_3/kernel:0', 'dense_3/bias:0'],)